# Cannot export a module in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to node.js and I am trying to build an application with it. When I want to export a module with module.exports to use it in the index.js file (the main file), an error is logged in the console saying that module is not defined.

I have tried to bundle the file with browserify, but every time I try browserify post.js -o bundle.js it says that it cannot find 'uws' (post.js is the file with the modules I want to use)

I have also tried adding a type="module" attribute to the script tag of the post.js file in html

```
The code of the post.js file is as follows:

module.exports.postForm = document.querySelector('.post-form');
module.exports.post = postForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const question = e.target['question'].value;
  const answer = e.target['answer'].value;

  postForm.question.value = '';
  postForm.answer.value = '';
})
```

Comment: Node.js is back-end and `document` is front-end. I think that you must first learn what node and browser is.

Comment: browserify bundles everything so works in the browser node-like. The problem that you are having when using browserify is that you are using a module that you have not installed. By the way, altough you install it, you will have problems because you cannot use it in the browser as `uws` requires native binaries. It only works on node environment. I recommend you to follow a node.js tutorial, read about browserify (or webpack, or rollup...) and understand what you are actually doing instead of copypasting things blindly.